# Newest references from Mendeley are not imported to Latex

Tags: bibliographies, overleaf, online, mendeley

In the beginning, the import of references from Mendeley worked well. However, now it does not import the newest references from Mendeley into Latex (overleaf).
When I click on the refresh button in latex it states:
*Imported from Mendeley at 6:39 pm Thu, 31st Jan 19*
So somehow it does not refresh to the actual date (22.02).
I installed Mendeley around 2 months ago and did not do any updates in Mendeley or Overleaf since then. I did not use any unusual references that I haven't used in the beginning, when it was still working
I would be really glad if somebody has an idea what the problem could be.
Best, Susi

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Currently, your question lacks a bit of detail necessary to answer it. You can edit by pressing the small _edit_ link below the question text. Most importantly: which program do you use to write your documents? TeXStudio? Overleaf? LyX? TeXnicCenter? Something else? Also: did you do any updates recently for Mendeley or for your editor? Did you add any unusual references in the past few weeks?

Comment: Thanks for your update, it is more clear now. I've changed the tags a bit, maybe that will help to attract attention from the right people. Meanwhile, you can also try to contact Overleaf support, they might be able to help you or to tell you how to get a log file or other debugging information for the Mendeley API calls.

Answer (score 3):

For future readers with this issue using Overleaf, you may try clicking the New File icon in the upper left-hand corner of your project, then click "From Mendeley." If it says that it's unable to refresh from the account, follow the link in the prompt and scroll down in order to unlink and re-link your Mendeley account. Then try refreshing your bibTex file.

I had to do this after changing my Mendeley password, and my existing references were not affected.

Even if you don't see the refresh error when adding a new file, re-linking your Mendeley may resolve this problem.

Comment: This problem still exists with the same solution

Comment: So others are aware, I believe this is now a premium feature as of accounts made [after Sep 2018](https://www.overleaf.com/blog/348-new-manage-shared-references-with-mendeley-groups)

Answer (score 2):

**Desktop or Web?**

Are you using Mendeley Desktop? If so, possibly you did not sync your Mendeley Desktop library with your Mendeley Web library. Overleaf links to your Mendeley Web account, so refreshing in Overleaf will only sync with the Mendeley Web library.

1. in Mendeley  Desktop go to `File` → `Synchronize Library`, or just press <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>
2. Now refresh the `.bib` file in your Overleaf project that is linked to Mendeley.
3. Recompile your LaTex document.

---

**Entire library or only group?**

Are you possibly importing only a specific Mendeley group? If so, then you need to make sure that the newly added references are not only added to the Mendeley library, but also to your specific group.

1. Add your new references to the desired Mendeley group.
2. If on Mendeley Desktop: Sync your Mendeley library (see above).
3. Now refresh the `.bib` file in your Overleaf project that is linked to Mendeley.
4. Recompile your LaTex document.